# How to create a template dashbord in tableu?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a Dashboard in tableau that I want to replicate it with another database that has the same columns/pills!

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to open the "template dashboard", add the new data source, then go to menu `DATA` => `Replace data source` and change the old data source to the new data source.
At this point close the old data source.

The fastest way, but this might not work, is to open the `.twb` file of the dashboard with Notepad and replace the old database name with the new one...of course something could be broke.
If you have a .twbx file you can open it with WinZip, WinRar, ... and find the `.twb` file inside.

Comment: If my 'new' data source have the same column of 'my old' the filters and meansuare fields , will be keep working? Have you ever made this?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could try 2 Options:

1. Take a copy of your template. In the Data Source tab, go to `Connections` -> `Edit Connection` to point it to the new data source.
2. In the template, create a new data source. Replace the Old data source with the new one by `Data` -> `Replace Data Source`.

For the formulas and filters to reflect on the new data source, make sure the *field names and data types are the same* as the old data source.

*Kindly note:* Editing the XML is **unsupported** by Tableau! Create a copy of your original workbook before attempting any XML editing, as this could potentially corrupt your workbook.